# pandas reshaping dataframe with different length rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a the following pandas data frame with the index on the left:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14
A17   a   b   1  AUG) NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
nn6   c   d   2  POS) e   f   2   Hi)
AZV   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
JFK   a   b   4   UUI) c   v   8   Yo)  t   f   9   po)
```

I'm looking to re-shape it to:

```
     0    1    2    3
A17  a    b    1   AUG)
nn6  c    d    2   POS)
nn6  e    f    2   Hi)
AZV  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
JFK  a    b    4   UUI)
JFK  c    v    8   Yo)
JFK  t    f    9   po
```

I have tried `reshape()` and used `itertools` to iterate over the columns but still can't seem to get it.

Basically, each time a ) is encountered then break to a new line.
The real table has over 150 columns.

thanks

Comment: Are the values always in multiples of four ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option that doesn't require iterating over rows (which can be very slow if there are many) is to do the following

```
[ins] In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
     0    1    2     3    4    5    6    7
A17  a    b    1  AUG)  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
nn6  c    d    2  POS)    e    f    2  HI)
AVZ     NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[ins] In [2]: joined = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(xi) for xi in x]), axis=1)
[ins] In [4]: split = joined.str.split(')', expand=True).reset_index(drop=False).melt(id_vars='index')

[ins] In [6]: split.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)

[ins] In [7]: split
Out[7]: 
  index                        value
0   A17                    a b 1 AUG
1   nn6                    c d 2 POS
2   AVZ  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
3   A17              nan nan nan nan
4   nn6                     e f 2 HI
5   AVZ                         None
6   A17                         None
7   nn6                             
8   AVZ                         None

[ins] In [8]: sel = split['value'].str.strip().str.len() > 0

[ins] In [9]: split = split.loc[sel, :]

[ins] In [9]: split
Out[9]: 
  index                        value
0   A17                    a b 1 AUG
1   nn6                    c d 2 POS
2   AVZ  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
3   A17              nan nan nan nan
4   nn6                     e f 2 HI

[ins] In [10]: out = split['value'].str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True)

[ins] In [11]: out.index = split['index']

[ins] In [12]: out
Out[12]: 
         0    1    2    3     4     5     6
index                                      
A17      a    b    1  AUG  None  None  None
nn6      c    d    2  POS  None  None  None
AVZ    nan  nan  nan  nan   nan   nan   nan
A17    nan  nan  nan  nan  None  None  None
nn6      e    f    2   HI  None  None  None
```

and then it's a matter of dropping the 4th to 6th column which is simple.
I added some of the output so that you can see what's happening in each step.

Comment: Thanks, tested on a df with 10,000 rows and >800 cols. Worked quickly.

Comment: Apply iterates over rows it doesn't use set based operations. surprised this solution worked quickly

Comment: @Manakin, note the axis argument. Apply is working on columns, taking each as a Series. So the number of loops is governed by the number of columns, not rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think an efficent way to concat the values would be to chunk the dataframe into 4 equal parts and re-concat it along the index.

The issue here is the column names which we can dynamically rename inside the concat statement.

```
import numpy as np 
lst = np.array_split([i for i in range(len(df.columns))],4)

[array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([ 8,  9, 10, 11]),
 array([12, 13, 14])]
```

---

```
dfs = pd.concat( [
        df.iloc[:,i].rename(columns=
                            dict(zip(df.iloc[:,i].columns,range(4)))
                            )
    
        for i in lst
    ]).dropna(how='all')
```

---

```
 print(dfs)

 0  1    2     3
A17  a  b  1.0  AUG)
nn6  c  d  2.0  POS)
JFK  a  b  4.0  UUI)
nn6  e  f  2.0   Hi)
JFK  c  v  8.0   Yo)
JFK  t  f  9.0   po)
```

the only diff here is that your missing a row from your desired output due to it being na.

we can do a union with `combine_first` to get the delta between the two dataframes.

```
dfs = dfs.combine_first(df.iloc[:,:0])

print(dfs)

       0    1    2     3
A17    a    b  1.0  AUG)
AZV  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
JFK    a    b  4.0  UUI)
JFK    c    v  8.0   Yo)
JFK    t    f  9.0   po)
nn6    c    d  2.0  POS)
nn6    e    f  2.0   Hi)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are other options, like slicing columns and appending, but this is pretty straightforward.

```
output = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = row.dropna().values
    if len(r) <= 4:
        output.append([index,*r])
    else:
        for x in np.reshape(r, (int(len(r)/4),4)):
            output.append([index,*x])
            
pd.DataFrame(output).set_index(0)
```